# EC2 Ubuntu 12.04 refuses do-release-upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, upgrade

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on EC2 and I want to upgrade to 14.04.

*do-release-upgrade* returns that there are no upgrades.

*do-release-upgrade -d* begins to work and then halts stating:

```
Calculating the changes

Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This can be caused by: 
* Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
```

I've been searching for a couple hours and have yet to find the right way to ask this question to lead to an answer. Starting from scratch is not a simple thing as I've do a lot to this VM, it's actually a template for a fairly decently large army. Anyway, I'm not a n00b. Help would be very awesome.

Comment: Hmm. HVM images can be upgraded, but I don't think old PV images can.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of do-release-upgrade (i,e. latest version of update-manager-core package).

Comment: @CraigMiskell yeah, it's fully up to date.

Comment: I think there isn't a good upgrade path.